# Wait for maximum 5 seconds

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am trying to implement something that waits for a boolean to be true. If after 5 seconds the boolean is still not true then i will execute the error message code

This is what I am doing now. But this method just waits for 5 seconds for all cases, which is wasting time. How can I do something like that this that executes as soon as the variable becomes true?

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
if (imageDisplayed == true) {
    //success
}
else {
    //failed
}
```

Comment: You should do a while loop for that, and soon as it hits time, do the deed.

Comment: What you *should* do is alter the code that's actually doing the work to do something much better than setting a boolean to indicate when it's done, such as calling a callback, returning a `Task` that indicates when it's done, firing an event, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use a [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

```
// Somewhere instantiate this as an accessible variable to both 
// display logic and waiting logic.
ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// In your thread where you want to wait for max 5 secs
if(resetEvent.WaitOne(5000)) {   // this will wait for max 5 secs before continuing.
    // do your thing
} else {
    // run your else logic.
}

// in your thread where you set a boolean to true
public void DisplayImage() {
    // display image
    display();

    // Notify the threads waiting for this to happen
    resetEvent.Set();   // This will release the wait/lock above, even when waiting. 
}
```

Rule of thumb. Better not use sleeps in your production code unless you have a really, really, really good reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't you forget to do a reset? Can I just do this with an `AutoResetEvent`?

Comment: You can reset as you see fit by calling resetEvent.reset after setting. With AutoResetEvent you have no control when it is set, so that is not directly great for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timeout variable to the time that you want to stop waiting and use that, along with the check that you're waiting for, as a condition in a while loop. In the example below, we just sleep for a tenth of a second between checks, but you can adjust the sleep time (or remove it) as you see fit:

```
var timeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);

while (!imageDisplayed && DateTime.Now < timeout)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

// Here, either the imageDisplayed bool has been set to true, or we've waited 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your sleeps up into "naps." ;)

```
for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    if (imageDisplayed)
    {
        // success
        break;
    }
}
//failed
```

Not quite instantly, but with a maximum 100ms latency.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop and checking incrementally for your condition

```
var waitedSoFar = 0;
var imageDisplayed = CheckIfImageIsDisplayed(); //this function is where you check the condition

while(waitedSoFar < 5000)
{
   imageDisplayed = CheckIfImageIsDisplayed();
   if(imageDisplayed)
   {
      //success here
      break;
   }
   waitedSoFar += 100;
   Thread.Sleep(100);
}
if(!imageDisplayed)
{
    //failed, do something here about that.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you want to use the [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Setup your boolean variable to execute a function when it is set to true

```
    System.Timers.Timer t;
    private bool val;
    public bool Val {
        get { return val; }
        set
        {
            if (value == true)
                // run function here
            val = value;
        }
    }
```

Then Setup your timers interval for every 5 seconds.

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        t = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

        t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
    }

    private void T_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

To start the timer simply use `t.Start()` and `t.Reset()` to reset the timer

Comment: should `val` be `imageDisplayed`, as in the example?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I was simply explaining the theory